# Proof involving vector orthogonal to subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to show this:

Let ${v_1,...,v_p}$ be a basis for a subspace $V$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$.  Prove that a vector $x$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is orthogonal to $V$ iff $x$ is orthogonal to all the vectors ${v_1,...,v_p}$.

Here's what I have:

If x is orthogonal to all the vectors ${v_1,...,v_p}$, then we know $x \cdot v_1=\ldots=x \cdot v_p = 0$.  Now, any vector in $V$ is a linear combination of these basis vectors: $v = c_1v_1 +\ldots+ c_pv_p$. So

$$
x\cdot v = x \cdot(c_1v_1 +\ldots+ c_pv_p)= c_1(x\cdot v_1) +\ldots+ c_p(x\cdot v_p)= c_1\cdot0+\ldots+c_p\cdot0=0
$$

So $x$ is orthogonal to $v$, where $v$ is an arbitrary vector in $V$.

Any hint on the other direction?

So we know $x$ is orthogonal to $V$, which means it's orthogonal to all vectors in $V$.  Since $v_1,\ldots,v_p$ is a basis for $V$, every vector in $V$ is a linear combination of these vectors.

I'm missing the jump to why this implies $x$ is orthogonal to each vector in the basis for $V$.

Help?

Thanks guys,
Mariogs

Comment: In the "other direction":  Are each of $v_1$ through $v_n$ in $V$?

Comment: The basis is contained in the space, so it is trivially true.

Comment: ah yeah, just set coefficient of given vector in basis to 1 and all other coefficients to 0

Answer (score 1):

For the other direction, if $x$ is orthogonal to $V$, then it is orthogonal to every vector in $V$. You may choose a particular vector $v \in V$, and $x$ will be orthogonal to it. Namely, you can choose each of the basis vectors for $v$. Since $v_i \in V$, and $x$ is orthogonal to every vector in $V$, then $x$ is orthogonal to $v_i$ for all $i$.